# Road cyclist keeps popping out of speedplay pedals

Tags: pedals

I've been riding for years and suddenly I've developed a problem with my right foot involuntarily popping out of my speedplay pedals.  New shoes/cleats and new pedals did not help.  I've even been checked out neurologically.  Any ideas?

Comment: What gave you the idea it was neurological and required medical consultation?

Comment: What is the release angle of your Speedplay's? (Some newer versions allow you to set this). I am trying to limit possibilities, for example, your old pedals were worn and release prematurely, but your new pedals have a reduced release angle, both result in you popping out earlier, but for different reasons.  Also under what riding conditions does this occur (e.g., constant pedaling, hills, sprint, etc)?

Comment: does it always pop out in the same place? Could you have, for example, raised your seatpost a touch so that when you hit the bottome of the stroke it makes the cleat release?

Comment: How's your leg power?  Are you growing stronger to the point that the speedplay mechanism is simply overpowered by your pedalling input ?

Comment: With SPDs this would happen if you're twisting your foot.  But I've never used Speedplays, so I don't know if this applies.

Comment: It could be the float angle as @Rider_X suggests. But... have you changed the height of your seatpost or position of your saddle recently? Even if you've just taken the seatpost off and replaced it for cleaning or transportation, you could find you've put it in a tiny bit too high, causing your hips to be a tiny bit tilted to accomodate this, leading to your right leg being extended a tiny bit further than before, so your ankle getting a tiny bit extended, and a tiny bit twisted and hitting the float limit on the cleat and then popping you off the pedal.

Answer (score 2):

Which Speedplay pedals? The ZERO model I used quite extensively had a pair of set screws on each cleat that would set the desired amount of float through the complete pedal stroke.

The only reason you should be popping out of a Speedplay pedal is due to lateral foot rotation through your pedal stroke (which is really just an extension of knee/hip dynamics), or your cleat is not secured to your shoe correctly (angle of the cleat body to the release point of the pedal's design), or your cleats are installed on the wrong shoe...

I realize this is an old question, but hope that my information might help another with a similar situation.

Comment: Being an old question isn't a problem at all, especially as it hadn't received a proper answer yet. Welcome to the site!